# Haskell: add multiple things to a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have an assigment and im kinda stuck:

```
xs = [4, 1]
ys = [3, 2]
```

the goal is to create a list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

I am allowed to use the following commands:
`head`, `tail`, `++`, `!!`, `reverse`, `take`, `drop`, `init`

I know that `tail xs ++ (reverse ys)` results in `[1, 2, 3]`

but how do i get the `4` at the end?

My "solution" would have been something along the lines of:

```
zs = tail xs ++ (reverse ys +++ (head xs)
zs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but instead im getting the following error:

```
<interactive>:39:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Num a, Num [a]) => [a]
```

The problem is i have no clue what that means
It would be nice if someone could explain me how the brackets work in haskell and how i can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unbalanced parentheses in your demonstrated attempt.

> ```
> tail xs ++ (reverse ys +++ (head xs)
> ```

Assuming you meant:

```
tail xs ++ (reverse ys ++ (head xs))
```

`head xs` is not a list, so using it with `++` will yield an error. But we can make it a list with a single element quite easily.

```
tail xs ++ (reverse ys ++ [head xs])
```

This now yields `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, but you can further remove the parentheses because of how `++` associates.

```
tail xs ++ reverse ys ++ [head xs]
```